# Keep track changes of DbContext with ObservableCollection in code first 

Tags: wpf, mvvm, commit, change-tracking

I'm using `ObservableCollection<T>` to bind some data to some view.
While I'm editing DB existing data, I can save data edits by calling only a single `Savechanges()` method in my view model, also add new items to collection and I can edit them, but the `SaveChanges()` method doesn't insert additional rows to db.

I don't know what entities are passed to the viewmodel. The T is a merged class of multiple entities so I have to do this. 
In Constructor:

```
collection=globalContext.TSet;
//the collection and context are defined in class level
```

Code to get a new item:

```
collection.Add(New T());
CurrentItem=collection.Last();
```

where collection is the `ObservableCollection<T>` and `CurrentItem` is the currently editing item.

***EDIT:***
The `context.ChangeTracker.Entries` doesn't recognise the new object.

I have a complex type(say T) which is the result of some join query,I have no idea that T is creating from which entities so I can not get the Entity => I can not say the context that what type of Entity I want to add.

So I have to force change tracker to create the new object from complex type which is the result of some join query.

I'm using  EF4.3.1

Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the new composed object's parts to the corresponding Dbsets in the constructor of T? Then they would be tracked and save changes on the context should work. But I'm not 100% sure if I understood the question correct...

Comment: @Sascha:The new T adds to the collection and as I set the new T's properties in my view model I can see properties that set in view model and the collection is contain the new T, but non of them affect in db after calling savechanges();.(thanks)

Comment: But an `ObservableCollection` doesn't know anything from the DbSet or your context. How should it guess what other logic should apply to the object just added to itself?

Answer (score 0):

The database is not getting updated.  Modify the DBSets in the view (or view model) via [IDbSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679233%28v=vs.103%29.aspx), then issue a DbContext.SaveChanges  Do this instead of directly modifying the ObservableCollection. The ObservableCollection should then refresh itself and update the view model and view.  If it does not requery the database to generate a new DbSet then get a new ObservableCollection from DbSet.Local for the view model then create a new view from that.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the new entity to TSet. You need to call TSet.Add(t) or hook up the CollectionChanged event of the ObservableCollection to do it automatically.